# Problems with model using LINQ to SQL when adding a strongly typed view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create a simple task manager solution based on the Nerd Dinner tutorial

weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/04/28/free-asp-net-mvc-nerddinner-tutorial-now-in-html.aspx.

EDIT: I have removed the http:// on these urls because I have not got enough rep to add links into a post.

I have built my model as shown here: nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part3.htm
It is identical except that Dinner is a task and RSVP is a project.

Relationship task.projectId -> project.projectId
I have more fields in these tables but I have kept the public partial task class in the model simple so far to match the tutorial.

My question is that when I try to add a new view and in the dialog I select "strongly typed view" my model class for the task does not show up in the drop down, anyone know why??

Probably a bit vague, i am just trying to get some ideas on why this could be happening.

I thought maybe my namespace was incorrect somewhere or my class was not public but it is.

I have got a reference to my repository in my controller by doing 
TaskRepository taskRepository = new TaskRepository();
and the controller has a using reference to TaskManager.Models;

All confusing me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how the dialog picks classes (other than it requires a clean compile), but you can just choose any random class and then edit the first line of the resulting aspx to substitute the class you prefer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of substituting it, I tried that but wanted to use the T4 template for detail scaffolding too and this was greyed out for me when I typed in my model name directly.
My code didnt have any highlighted errors but I didnt try compiling so I will try that later today. Thanks

Comment: Your correct in saying I should do a build. I was missing a "using System.Data.Linq;" on my task class and fixed that did a build and then worked fine. Thanks